# f-spot on ubuntu 14.04 stopped displaying any pictures

Tags: ubuntu, images

For a while now, I've had a serious problem with f-spot on my Lenovo X250, which runs Ubuntu 14.04 with MATE. After a security and software update earlier this year, f-spot stopped displaying the pictures in the archive. Neither the icons in the browser nor the full pictures in the slide show are displayed. I also cannot import anything from my camera.

I hoped this would be a temporary glitch but it is not. It still doesn't work after several months. On my older Lenovo X200s it still works and I don't dare update the software on that machine. My feeling is that this is a library issue but I cannot find out what it is and didn't find anything similar on the internet.

Here is the output of `uname -a` for my system:

```
Linux ****** 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here are a few error messages when starting from a terminal:

```
(f-spot:3835): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_8_FSpot_Widgets_CellRendererTextProgress::value after class was initialised

(f-spot:3835): Gdk-WARNING **: losing last reference to undestroyed window


Unhandled Exception:
GLib.GException: Unrecognized image file format
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader.Close () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSpot.Loaders.GdkImageLoader.Close () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSpot.Loaders.GdkImageLoader.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSpot.Loaders.GdkImageLoader.Finalize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Try running `f-spot` from a terminal and add any error messages you see to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here is one error message that pops up:  (f-spot:3713): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_8_FSpot_Widgets_CellRendererTextProgress::value after class was initialised

Comment: Is there any possibility that you can find some similar software until this bug is fixed? Also, is the bug reported?

Comment: @PeterYeti please *[edit]* your question and include the error. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Comment: @schaiba: I have a f-spot archive with almost a Tb of pictures. Switching to a different program would be highly impractical. I didn't find by problem when searching, which really surprised me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Next time, please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it look like code and don't add "edit:" or similar messages. The SE sites are all about Q&A and the idea is that I can understand your question the first time I read it. I don't need to know that you've edited it (although that information is available in the [edit history](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/305231/revisions). Whenever you edit your posts, just make it so that they say what you would have said if posting it for the first time.